# Nextjs Appdir export const revalidate = 0 gives 500 error when going directly to page

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I have a checkout page in the appDir where I am fetching the paymentIntent from stripe. When I go by next navigation to the page it works correctly but if I go directly to example.com/checkout it gives me an internal server error 500 (A client-side exception has occurred). This issue only happens when deployed in my development environment I can go directly to localhost:3000/checkout without issue.

Code example:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import Questionnaire from '../components/Questionnaire';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Checkout',
  openGraph: {
    title: 'Checkout',
  },
  robots: {
    index: false,
    follow: false,
  },
};

export const revalidate = 0;

async function getStripeIntent() {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

  return await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 999,
    currency: 'usd',
  });
}

export default async function Page() {
  const { client_secret } = await getStripeIntent();

  return (
    <main className='container container--small'>
      <Questionnaire clientSecret={client_secret} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

I know what is causing the error is the line `export const revalidate = 0` because when I remove it the page loads in production but then everyone would get the same stripe payment intent. As a workaround I have set the revalidate const to equal `0.01` but it would be much better if it was `0`.